# Ubuntu Screen terminates jar when I termiante SSH

Tags: gnu-screen

Im having a very weird problem: I have a jar with a scheduledthreadpoolexecutor. When I run the jar in the screen session and detach from it, it works perfectly. I can reattach, everything is running as it should. As soon as I disconnect SSH (also witch detached screen) the jar execution will stop immediately. By reconnecting the screen session is still available.

I first believed that it was maybe a unexpected Error in the program, but through very advanced testing, i am positive that it has nothing to do with any unexpected errors in the jar (the program runs perfectly as long as i keep connected to the vps).

What files can I share you? I know this is a very vague question, but I don't even know what could cause the problem. If you need any files, please let me know, will upload them asap.

Comment: Have you tested screen is running while you're disconnected. I usually create mine with `screen -dms name`

Comment: The screen will be available, but the jar stops running. When I only detach and reattach everything is working as expected